# C++ stream insertion operator returns bit instead of string

Tags: c++, io

my problem is that my stream insertion operator function returns a string like "0x55d55d9a6eb0" when I try using it through cout instead of a multi line descriptive string which comes from the output << line, here's the relevant code. For context, it's a template class which has a stream insertion operator trying to print out a multi line string.

```
template <class V>
//friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Report<V>&);
//CORRECTED VERSION:
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Report<V>*);
...
template <class V>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const Report<V>& b)
{
  for(int i = 0;i<b.rows.size();i++){
    output << b.rows[i].row <<endl;// b.rows[i].row is a 1 line string
  }
  return output;
}
...
//how I am using the stream insertion operator in a seperate function:

void Main::print(Report<int> *r) {
    cout << r <<endl;//I have tried changing to &r, *r but no luck
}
```

Comment: Not enough relevant code. You could also try changing your `endl` to `'\n'`. You rarely have to manually flush, and constantly flushing while you're trying to insert into the stream seems less than ideal. BUT, the biggest problem is you overloaded `operator<<()` for a `Report<V>` but pass a `Report<V>*`. You're just printing an address.

Comment: @sweenish do you think I could de reference the pointer with &&? Would that work

Answer (score 0):

My problem was trying to use a pointer object with a stream insertion that takes an address, after changing the stream insertion operator to take a pointer everything worked.